# Group records finding a MIN and MAX without changing the order of the records.Gaps and Islands?

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, partition

**EDIT - since no-one seems to have an answer for me, could someone tell me how to accomplish this within Crystal Reports? I wanted to use SQL to create the view with the groupings as described, but I could also do the grouping within Crystal if someone could help me with that?
I am desperate!
Thank you! Lisa

**ORIGINAL Post - I would like to group records together using MIN and MAX values without disturbing the order the records are in. (however I am not certain that using MIN/MAX is the way to do this, I read about "gaps and island" and also about a "partition" function which might be what I am supposed to use...?)

The POC and POT values must stay in order as they are a linear value on a road. In other words, the POC 10500 is the very beginning of the road and 16000 is the very end of the road and the values in between are events happening along the road which need to stay in that linear order.

```
CREATE TABLE RoadStations
(`id` int, `roadname` varchar(15), `inspection` date, `POC` int, `POT` int, `rate` varchar(2), `up` varchar(2))

INSERT INTO RoadStations
(`id`, `roadname`, `inspection`,`POC`,`POT`,`rate`,`up`)
VALUES
(1, 'A Branch', '20150321', 10500, 10900, 'C', 1 ),
(2, 'A Branch', '20150510', 10900, 11500, 'C', 1 ),
(3, 'A Branch', '20150510', 11500, 12000, 'C', 1 ),
(4, 'A Branch', '20150510', 12000, 13200, 'C', 1 ),
(5, 'A Branch', '20150510', 13200, 14500, 'C', 1 ),
(6, 'A Branch', '20150510', 14500, 14800, 'C', 1 ),
(7, 'A Branch', '20150510', 14800, 15100, 'C', 2 ),
(8, 'A Branch', '20150510', 15100, 16000, 'C', 1 )

SELECT * FROM RoadStations

ID   roadname    inspection        POC      POT    rate  up
1    A Branch    Mar 21, 2015      10500    10900    C    1
2    A Branch    May 10, 2015      10900    11500    C    1
3    A Branch    May 10, 2015      11500    12000    C    1
4    A Branch    May 10, 2015      12000    13200    C    1
5    A Branch    May 10, 2015      13200    14500    C    1
6    A Branch    May 10, 2015      14500    14800    C    1
7    A Branch    May 10, 2015      14800    15100    C    2
8    A Branch    May 10, 2015      15100    16000    C    1
```

I need to query on the above table to group values in the following way:

Row 1 should be grouped as its own row with POC 10500, POT 10900 because the date changes to a new value in Row 2.

Rows 2-6 should be grouped as one row with POC 10900, POT 14800 because values are all the same until the value of "up" changes on row 7.

Row 7 should be grouped as its own row with POC 14800, POT 15100 because the value of "up" changes again in row 8.

Row 8 should be grouped as its own row with POC 15100, POT 16000 because the value of "up" changes once again.

Using a regular GROUP function does not work:

```
SELECT
  roadname, inspection, min(POC), max(POT), rate, up
FROM
  RoadStations
GROUP BY roadname, inspection, rate, up

roadname    inspection        POC      POT    rate  up
A Branch    Mar 21, 2015      10500    10900    C    1
A Branch    May 10, 2015      10900    16000    C    1
A Branch    May 10, 2015      14800    15100    C    2
```

The above grouping is not the result I want because it grouped row 8 in with the row 2-6 records.

This is the result I DO WANT:

```
roadname    inspection        POC      POT    rate  up
A Branch    Mar 21, 2015      10500    10900    C    1
A Branch    May 10, 2015      10900    14800    C    1
A Branch    May 10, 2015      14800    15100    C    2
A Branch    May 10, 2015      15100    16000    C    1
```

As you can see, the order of the POC and POT values have not been disturbed in the grouping process.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty complicated logic. One option you could use is to write a function.

I would define some variables and a cursor like so:

```
DECLARE _currentroad varchar(15);
DECLARE <other variables to store values of POC, POT, rate, up>
DECLARE CUR1 CURSOR FOR SELECT roadname, inspection, POC, POT, rate, up from RoadStations;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
```

and fetch it into variables in a loop:

```
OPEN CUR1;
REPEAT
    FETCH cur1 INTO @roadname, @inspection, @poc, @pot, @rate, @up
    IF NOT done THEN
        <your business logic goes here>
    END IF;
UNTIL done END REPEAT;
```

This is where it gets more involved. You will need to populate the variables you declared if they are empty, then keep comparing those values to the next fetched row.

As you fetch rows, if the none of your 'group by' values (roadname, inspection, rate, and up) changes you will need to replace the value of your POT variable with the newer one, then print the saved values when you find a row that resets the loop (when roadname, inspection, rate, or up change).

Comment: I need to end up with a VIEW in oracle so I can join it to a spatial data layer in arcmap. I'm not sure your suggestion would work in that regard?

Comment: I hope you've already found a solution to your problem. If not, I would suggest revisiting your data model. The table you are using is not well-designed, and should be broken up if possible.  Without understanding your data better, it seems it should be pretty simple to break up that table into at least a "road" or "roadstations" table, and another for inspection. Good table design generally seems to solve these problems whenever I see them.

Comment: Thanks but they are actually different tables that have been joined together already with SQL. The table I provided is the outcome of the several tables being joined together. The code for that is massive and I just simplified it here. I can't change the data. Its unfortunate, I was hoping there was a way to further manipulate the data to get what I need.